# Set Realm query filter programmatically with Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, realm

Is it possible to set Realm query filters programmatically?

**Background**
My app is a habit based app working on streaks of consecutive 7 day check ins; 7 days of consecutive check ins = 1 streak.

Within the object: "Streak" there are columns named:

`Day 1 | Day 2 | ... | Day 7`

**An example query is:**

```
let todayCheckIn = realm.objects(Streak).filter("Day1" == 1).sorted("StartDate").last
```

This is checking the Realm object `Streak` and if the user has "Checked In" represented by a `1` in the column `Day1`.

I could use a series of If/Else statements to select a query, but I would prefer to have Swift determine which column to filter on, and set this programatically - using only one query

e.g.

```
let day = "Day1"
let todayCheckIn = realm.objects(Streak).filter(day == 1).sorted("StartDate").last
```

I've tried:

```
let todayCheckIn = realm.objects(Streak).filter(\(day) == 1).sorted("StartDate").last
```

But that doesn't work either. 
 
Is there a way I can set a Realm query filter programatically like this?
 Many thanks!

Comment: Show `Streak` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter()` takes an `NSPredicate` format string, which supports `%K` for dynamically supplied key names:

```
let day = "Day1"
let todayCheckIn = realm.objects(Streak).filter("%K = 1", day).sorted("StartDate").last
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define and build an `NSPredicate`. Something like this should work:

```
let day = "Day1"
let formatString = day + " == %@"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: formatString, 1)
let todayCheckIn = realm.objects(Streak).filter(predicate).sorted("StartDate").last
```